# jqGrid Unformatter for predefined formatter

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid where the formatter function for the colModel must be defined as a string

```js
{name:'FileSize', index:'FileSize', width:90, editable: true, 
                                            formatter: 'fileSizeFormatter'}
```

I can't use the following where the formatter function is not a string because I build the colmodels on the server side in C#. If I could use the non string formatter Defining unformatter would be a solution as shown in 
[Here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter)

```js
{name:'FileSize', index:'FileSize', width:90, editable: true, 
                                                formatter: fileSizeFormatter}
```

And here is the fileSizeFormatter I needed to use fn.fmatter because my formatter is passed as a string and the code assumes it is one of the predefined one's lile "select", "currency"...etc

```js
$.fn.fmatter.fileSizeFormatter = function (cellval, options) {
    var fileUnit = "B";
    if (cellval) {
        var fileUnit;
        var iKBFileSize;
        if (cellval < 1024) {
            iKBFileSize = cellval;
        } else {
            iKBFileSize = cellval / 1024;
            fileUnit = "KB";
        }

        var result = iKBFileSize.toFixed(1) + fileUnit;
        return result;
    }

    return cellval + fileUnit;
};
```

[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/86/)

So the question is how can I define unformatter for a formatter which is passed as a string. When I do grid.getrowdata or edit the cell my unformatter is not being used. It is getting me the data with the file unit.

```js
$.unformat.fileSizeFormatter = function (cellvalue, options, cell) {
    return $('input', cellval).is(":checked") ? true : false;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define unformatter in a little another way:

```js
$.fn.fmatter.fileSizeFormatter.unformat = function (cellValue, options, elem) {
    return $(elem).find('input').is(":checked") ? true : false;
}
```

You should define unformatter of cause after defining the formatter (`$.fn.fmatter.fileSizeFormatter`).